# Correct way to achieve mutex operation using lockf utility in shell script

Tags: shell, concurrency, mutex, freebsd, csh

I was looking to add a mutex to my shell script. It is possible with flock but the utility is not installed on my shell and will not be able to install this utility or any other utilities.
I tried using lockf instead to acquire lock but could not get it to work as expected. Below is the snippet of what I was trying to do.

```
lockf -k /tmp/lock "echo $$ > lock"
echo "locked"
sleep 10

rm -f /tmp/lock
echo "unlocked
```

Ideally if we run this script on two terminals the second instance should be waiting for lock until the first instance deletes the lock file. Where am I going wrong?. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: And what is `lockf`? What OS are you using? (`flock(1)` is generally only on Linux IIRC...)

Comment: I am using freebsd. The shell is csh.

Comment: Thanks Shawn as you mentioned flock is available only on linux and not on freebsd

Comment: Looks like it comes with NetBSD too, actually. I don't have a Free VM set up to mess with, though.

Comment: Okay, from the FreeBSD manpage for `lockf(1)`, it's just  their version of `flock(1)`. So it acquires a lock on the file, runs the command it's given (Don't know if that's done through a shell or not; your redirection attempt might not work), and then releases the lock - which will happen very quickly because `echo` doesn't take any time to speak of. Then the rest of your script runs.

Comment: @Shawn Your explanation make sense. But since -k option is used I was expecting the lock to be present until I delete the file explicitly. I went through the manpage again.  I guess only the file is retained but not the lock.

Comment: That's correct. The lock is released when `lockf` exits.

Answer (score 0):

For example, If you would like to have a `cron` every minute but want to prevent running multiple times your script, you could use something like:

```
* * * * * lockf -t 0 /tmp/foo.lock /path/to/foo.sh
```

In this case, `lockf` will create the lock file `/tmp/foo.lock` and automatically will remove on exit.

The option `-t 0` prevents creating too many `lockf` processes, it can be read as *wait N seconds for the lock to be removed or exit*, if the `-t N` is not specified  `lockf` will wait indefinitely.

From the [lockf man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lockf):

> ```
> -t   seconds   Specifies a timeout for waiting for the lock.  By default,
>      lockf waits indefinitely to acquire the lock.  If a timeout
>      is specified with this option, lockf will wait at most the
>      given number of seconds before giving up.  A timeout of 0 may
>      be given, in which case lockf will fail unless it can acquire
>      the lock immediately.  When a lock times out, command is not
>      executed.
> ```

Once you have the lock file you could test like this:

```
lockf -t 0 /tmp/foo.lock uname
```

And will get something like:

```
lockf: /tmp/foo.lock: already locked
```